# Best way to re organize a subversion repository?

Tags: svn

So the challenge is this:

We have a single SVN repository server, that contains multiple projects:

```
http://server.com/svn/projectA/trunk
http://server.com/svn/projectA/branches
http://server.com/svn/projectA/tags

http://server.com/svn/projectB/trunk
http://server.com/svn/projectB/branches
http://server.com/svn/projectB/tags
```

ProjectA and ProjectB are really just components of ProjectX. What everyone wants now is:

```
http://server.com/svn/projectX/trunk/ProjectA
http://server.com/svn/projectX/trunk/ProjectB 
http://server.com/svn/projectX/branches/OldVersion/ProjectA 
http://server.com/svn/projectX/branches/OldVersion/ProjectB 
http://server.com/svn/projectX/tags/PreMajorChange/ProjectA 
http://server.com/svn/projectX/tags/PreMajorChange/ProjectB
```

I was thinking svndump, but then to recheckin all that data sort means that our revision numbers will exceed 100,000. Not sure that's the best way to go about it (or maybe that's the only way).

Or would be it as simple as svn move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `svn move`. It will preserve the history and will increase SVN repository size minimally.
First you checkout the repository at root level, and then do the moves:

```
mkdir -p projectX/{trunk,branches/OldVersion,tags/PreMajorChange}

svn add projectX

svn move projectA/trunk projectX/trunk/ProjectA

svn move projectA/branches/* projectX/branches/OldVersion/ProjectA

svn move projectA/tags/* projectX/tags/PreMajorChange/ProjectA

svn move projectB/trunk projectX/trunk/ProjectB

svn move projectB/branches/* projectX/branches/OldVersion/ProjectB

svn move projectB/tags/* projectX/tags/PreMajorChange/ProjectB

svn commit . -m "Restructuring"
```

Try it first on a test repository (for example copy existing one by `svnadmin hotcopy`).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to preserve the commit history, even not explicitly written?

You can create a new repo for ProjectX, and then link projects A and B into it using svn:externals property. Its like symlinks in a plain FS. you can read a quick sample [here](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Short-tutorial-on-svn-propset-for-svnexternals-p.html).

This is the simpler way as you don't have to do some "dangerous" operations.

Comment: You can create a new repo for ProjectX, and then link projects A and B into it using svn:externals property. Its like symlinks in a plain FS.